# how to schedule an automatic call to a stored procedure in MySQL every hour between 12:00PM - 12:00AM

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

How can I create a trigger to call a MySQL stored procedure every hour between 12:00PM - 12:00AM every day?
This is what I have done to call the prosedure every hour every day. but I don't want it to run 24 times a day. I only want it to run between  12-12 only.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` EVENT `prod_trig` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2014-01-17 18:15:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'This.....' 
DO CALL `gd`.`prod_update_tr`()
```

Comment: use a simple if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html) to call this procedure in the desired timespan of the day only:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` EVENT `prod_trig` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2014-01-17 18:15:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'This.....' 
IF CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '12:00:00' THEN
    CALL `gd`.`prod_update_tr`();
END IF
|
DELIMITER ;
```